# rust increase the capacity of a vector by n

Tags: rust, vector, allocation

I'm working on leetcode problem 88 https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-sorted-array/description/?envType=study-plan-v2&envId=top-interview-150 which merges a vector into another vector. Therefore the first vector is extended by a known amount. However, as some calculations need to be performed when merging the two vectors it's not possible to simply use an iterator and .extend().

Therefore I am looking for a way to to increase the capacity of the vector by a known amount (or two a known value) similar to how `Vec::with_capacity()` can be used to allocate a vector with a known capacity. Thanks,

Comment: [`Vec::reserve`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.reserve).

Comment: @Masklinn thanks, not sure how I missed that the first time

Comment: This is one good example why Stackoverflow is broken. This is a valid question, well formulated and still gets a drive-by negative vote with no reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [reserve](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.reserve) to extend the capacity of an existing vector.